# Printing character array error in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

While trying this code in C, I'm seeing garbage value in main method. What mistake I'm doing?

I hope that I should use "%s" in main method also but seems like wrong. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* minimumMultiple(int num);

int main(void) {
// your code goes here
printf("%s", minimumMultiple(13)); // prints  -  *p·ä…d¿“¿Eƒ (GARBAGE) - WHY?
return 0;
}

char* minimumMultiple(int num) {
int chars1s = 1, rem = 1;
while (rem != 0) {
    rem = (rem*10+1) % num;
    chars1s++;
}
char chars[chars1s];
int i;
printf("%d\n", chars1s); // prints 6 
for (i=0;i<chars1s;i++) {
    chars[i] = '1';
}
chars[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",chars); // prints "111111"
return chars;
}
```

Comment: `chars` is local storage which should not be returned for further usage outside of its scope ( as the stack can and will overwrite it )

Comment: `chars[i] = '\0';` writes one past the array invoking Undefined Behavior. Fix it by changing `char chars[chars1s];` to `char chars[chars1s + 1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an address for locale variable `chars` in `minimumMultiple`.

```
test_c.c:25:5: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return chars;
```

You should define `chars` as a pointer.

```
 char *chars = malloc(chars1s + 1);
```

Comment: I see. What are some ways to solve this?

Comment: define chars as a pointer, see the updated answer

Comment: Now how it's solving the problem. It's just storing the variable in heap I guess?

Comment: Ah I think earlier it was going in function's stack which was vanished after the call.

Comment: @Prakhar Yes. You are right. Don't forget to free the `malloc`ed memory. Another way to solve this problem would be to use a global or a static variable. Both have `static` storage duration and exists as long as the program does.

Comment: @Prakhar Yeah, this allows you to access it from main, before you couldn't. Just want to add that this is leaking memory.

Comment: @wallek876 Oh yep nice point you raised. I should nullify it after the things. Should I use free or initialize with null?

Comment: @Prakhar Both are different. By assigning the pointer to `NULL`, you lose the allocated memory, leading to a memory leak. **`free` it**. That's the right way to do it.